# Matlab cell like structure in python

Tags: python, matlab, data-structures, cell

I am trying to generate a list of arrays in python similar to the Matlab code below:

```
for(t=1:Nmax)
    thisCell{t} = zeros(i,j,k)
end
```

anyone has an idea how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension and numpy:

```
thisCell = [ numpy.zeros(shape=(i,j,k)) for t in range(1, Nmax) ]
```

Comment: what if i,j,k are changing for evert t,can we still do it?